# Microsoft Word 2010: Using indexes - with and without cross-references

Tags: microsoft-word

I am currently writing my thesis using Microsoft Word 2010.

I would like to use one index for referencing technical terms at the back of the thesis as can usually be found in books<sup>1</sup>. This index should list the terms and their occurences within the text (i.e. page numbers). It should not include cross-reference texts.

I would like to use another index for listing and describing nomenclature/abbreviations<sup>2</sup>. I wanted to use the mechanisms Microsoft Word provides in order to prevent errors (re-introduction of abbreviations, forgotten abbreviations, etc.).

**An example** (¶ view in MS Word being activate):

> Foobar{·XE·"Foobar"·},·Bananrama{·XE·"Bananarama"·}¶
>
> Banana{·XE·"Banana"·\t·"Is a fruit"·},·, APL{·XE·"APL"·\t·"Is another fruit"·}

Foobar and Bananarama were inserted without cross-references. I want to use them as technical terms that will be described in the text in a broader detail or I simply want them later be easily accessed by a lookup in the index<sup>1</sup>.

Banana and APL are short technical terms and abbreviations that get a short explanation as a cross-reference.

**What I get:**

[image: What I get]

**What I want:**
(two indexes with different content)

[image: What I want]

Is this possible or am I using it wrong?

Thanks!

---

<sup>1</sup> German: "Stichwortverzeichnis", "Sachwortverzeichnis", "Sachwortregister"; translates to "index" 
<sup>2</sup> German: "Abkürzungsverzeichnis", "Glossar"

Answer (score 0):

You can add a switch to an XE field to identify that you want the "definitions" to appear in a separate index (ie not as part of your main index that has the page numbers).

For your Banana and APL XE fields, you would add the switch \f "n".  It doesn't have to be "n" but I just adopted that for "nomenclature".  The only other switch you need is the \e followed by tab character inside quote marks.

You would then insert 2 different Index fields, one "standard" one which will pick up the general entries and display page numbers (see screenshot below).

[image]

The second Index field would also include the \f "n" switch.  You won't be able to generate the index as a table, but you have 2 options here:

1. Modify the format of the Index1 paragraph style so that it has a hanging indent at, say, 5 cm.  Because of the \e switch with a tab character (enclosed in quotes), your text should nicely align in 2 "columns" (and longer blocks of text will wrap correctly under the "second column".  You could also bold the "Banana" part of the XE fields to make your definitions stand out, and also format the Index1 style to add, say, 12pt after spacing (NB: changes to the Index1 style will also affect your page number index);

OR

2. Update this second Index and then convert the field back to text (CTRL SHIFT F9).  Then select all of the (now) text for this and Convert Text to Table with tabs as separator.  This will give you a 2 column table.  (NB:  This won't automatically update, so when you finish your thesis, you could delete the existing table, insert a new Index field and convert it back to text then table again).